# About screen area cursor jumping in vscode's vimExtension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, ideavim

I found that in vscode's vimExtension
Use "leader+leader+l" (vscode's default leader key is space) ("hljk" is fine) to jump to the specified location quickly

This is a perfect feature, but it doesn't seem to be available in native vim.
idea in ideaideaVim also does not (I installed aceJump to achieve a similar function), eclipse's Vrapper also does not have this feature

I hope the seniors will tell me where I didn't get it.

```
before "space+space+l"
```

[image: before]

```
after "space+space+l"
```

[image: after]

```
"gu" then
```

[image: gu finish]

Comment: Did you consider reading [the extension's page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim#vim-easymotion)? The answer is right there in your file at line 111.

Comment: Oh, got it, I just need to figure out how easymotion behaves in other vim-like operations
(I haven't used native vim and his plugins, so it seems like a silly question)
But thank you very much for replying to my question, it has benefited me a lot and I wish you a good life.
Thanks~!